# Can I use both wildcard and Link element inside the Compile element?

Tags: msbuild, csproj

In the `.csrpoj` file, If I have

```
<Compile Include="c:\path\File1.cs">
  <Link>Dir1\File1.cs</Link>
</Compile>
```

Then Visual Studio shows that file as a shortcut under `Dir1` folder in the Solution Explorer.

If I have

```
<Compile Include="c:\path\*.cs"></Compile>
```

Then all `.cs` files show up as shortcuts in Solution Explorer at top level:

Is there a way to include *all* files in some folder and make then show up under a sub-folder? Omitting the filename in `Link` element does not work:

```
<Compile Include="c:\path\*.cs">
  <Link>Dir1\</Link>
</Compile>
```

The files still show up at top level.

How do I include all files in a folder and still use the Link element? The reason I need this is, I need to include files from multiple folders and some of them have the same name. Two files at top level cannot have the same name.

Any other way to achieve this?

Comment: @leppie I am able to use Wildcards without the Link element.

Comment: But as I said, not possible for a `Link` child. Have you tried `<Link>Dir1\*.cs</Link>` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried <Link>Dir1\\*.cs</Link>; VS complains of invalid characters.

Comment: Then it is not possible, like I said.

Comment: So how do I include all files from multiple folders that is not in project hierarchy considering there may be duplicate names?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
<Content Include="..\..\SomeDirectory\**\*.xml">
  <Link>SomeLinkDirectoryOfYourChoosing\%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

Comment: This does not work as is for me. But if I give a dummy name instead of wildcards then it works:     
<Content Include="..\..\primary-key-delete-then-insert\generated\*.cs">
      <Link>fse\xyz.cs</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>

Note dummy name xyz.cs. The files show up under folder fse in solution explorer

Comment: It should be mentioned that any property change of included file links in VS replaces this single general items definition with set of them (for each included file).

Comment: Just to add one more note to this: if you are using the <Content> tag, the form %(Filename)%(Extension) won't work.  That would be if you are, for example, trying to have a set of files compiled.  However, for anyone trying to get files copied to their output directory, using the <None> tag, the %(Filename)%(Extension) form will work (and if you're lucky will be slightly less confusing to the next person to look at it).

Comment: I had a similar requirement that I solved with:     
     <None Include="..\..\..\configs\Backend\**\*">
   <Link>Config\%(RecursiveDir)\xx')</Link>
    </None>

Answer (score 33):

Others have suggested the using the `Link` attribute with placeholders, which indeed works. However, Microsoft has implemented a new attribute (which isn't in any of my code completion suggestions), named `LinkBase`, shown below.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Compile Include="..\SomeDirectory\*.cs" LinkBase="SomeDirectoryOfYourChoosing" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Sources:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2795
- https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/pull/1246
- [Link Additional Files in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44423582/link-additional-files-in-visual-studio)

Comment: This is the best, leanest answer :)

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of others, here's the answer plus the comment from Dean and Miserable Variable, which I found useful:

I have two projects, and I need to include *.xsd from one in the other, without copying the files or having to update the referencing csproj file every time a new XSD is added to the first.

The solution was to add the following to the csproj file

```
  <Content Include="..\BusinessLayer\Schemas\*.xsd">
    <Link>Contract\Schemas\xxx.xsd</Link>
  </Content>
```

Note xxx.xsd, you have to give a dummy filename in the `Link` element. It just gets replaced.

Also, you can include all sub folders with:

```
  <Content Include="..\BusinessLayer\Schemas\**\*.xsd">
    <Link>Contract\Schemas\ThisTextDoesntMatter</Link>
  </Content>
```

And files of all type (useful for pulling in CSS/JS/Style folders from 3rd parties) with:

```
  <Content Include="..\PresentationLayer\CustomerStyle\**\*.*">
    <Link>CustomerStyle\placeHolder</Link>
  </Content>
```

Answer (score 2):

To include subfolders:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="..\SomeExternalFolder\**\*.cs" LinkBase="YourProjectFolder" />
</ItemGroup>
```