# Link Additional Files in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, csproj

I am trying to include stylecop.json in my C# project on Visual Studio 2017. I have figured out how to do this by modifying the .csproj in any text editor:

```xml
<AdditionalFiles Include="stylecop.json">
    <Link>stylecop.json</Link>
</AdditionalFiles>
```

I am wondering if there is a way to do this without making any text edits. I understand I can always add it like any other files but that would make a copy of the file within project folder and not link it externally.

Answer (score 7):

You can add a `Directory.Build.targets` file somewhere in your solution directory (will apply to all projects at or below that directory) with the following contents:

```xml
    <Project>
      <ItemGroup>
        <AdditionalFiles Update="@(AdditionalFiles)">
          <Link Condition="'%(Link)' == ''">%(Identity)</Link>
       </AdditionalFiles>
      </ItemGroup>
    </Project>
```

Note that using `%(Identity)` here isn't optimal for items outside the "project cone" - e.g. when you have `<AdditionalFiles Include="..\..\foo.bar" />`. For this you can use a mechanism similar to what [SDK-based projects will do](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/pull/1246) in VS 2017 15.3 / .net core 2.0 tooling:

```xml
    <Project>
      <ItemGroup>
        <AdditionalFiles Update="@(AdditionalFiles)">
          <LinkBase Condition="'%(LinkBase)' != ''">$([MSBuild]::EnsureTrailingSlash(%(LinkBase)))</LinkBase>
          <Link Condition="'%(Link)' == '' And !$([MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault('%(FullPath)', '').StartsWith($([MSBuild]::EnsureTrailingSlash($(MSBuildProjectDirectory)))))">%(LinkBase)%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
       </AdditionalFiles>
      </ItemGroup>
    </Project>
```

This will even preserve directory hierarchies of items matched with e.g. `..\shared\**\*.json` and the target folder could be set using the `LinkBase` metadata:

```xml
    <AdditionalFiles Include="..\shared\**\*">
      <LinkBase>SharedFiles</LinkBase>
    </AdditionalFiles>
```

Note that you may need to close and re-open the solution after making changes to `Directory.Build.targets`. In the upcoming VS 2017 15.3 update, changes will be monitored by VS automatically. In previous versions, the file will be cached by VS until the solution is closed.